# How do I create a jar using armed bear common lisp?

Tags: java, common-lisp

I was wondering if it's possible to create a jar file using armed bear common lisp and if so how to do it.

So in other words, I have this following code (format t "Hello, World!~%")) I can run it in armed bear common lisp. I was wondering how I could create a jar that executes that code.–

Thanks,

Shaun.

Comment: What does your question mean? Please don't repeat the current wording. A jar file is literally a zip file with a special file for some metadata. You can certainly add the abcl classes to any jar. Are you asking how to create a fat jar? Or are you asking how to create a fat jar and invoke a LISP repl on startup? Or are you asking how to create a fat jar and invoke a LISP program on startup? Also, are you expecting us to create an entire bespoke tutorial on all of the above? Also, how is it that my comment is so much longer than your question?

Comment: So if I have this following code (format t "Hello, World!~%")) I can run it in armed bear common lisp. I was wondering how I could create a jar that executes that code. I hope thta makes sense. Thank you

Comment: Might be useful https://www.didierverna.net/blog/index.php?post/2011/01/22/Towards-ABCL-Standalone-Executables

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documentation](https://common-lisp.net/project/armedbear/releases/1.6.0/abcl-1.6.0.pdf) says (in section 3.3, sorry for the pdf) -

> ## 3.3.2 Implemented JSR-223 interfaces
>
> JSR-223 defines three main interfaces, of which two (`Invocable` and `Compilable`) are optional.
>   ABCL implements all the three interfaces - `ScriptEngine` and the two optional ones - almost
>   completely.

#### Creating an executable jar **with** ABCL in five easy steps

Step one: Creating a fat jar containing Armed Bear.

I'm going to use maven because it's what I know. Let's create a `pom.xml` file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.stackoverflow.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ColbertNightmare</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Stephen Colbert's Nightmare - Armed Bears</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.abcl</groupId>
            <artifactId>abcl</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>ColbertNightmare</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.stackoverflow.example.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Step two: We need to follow the maven standard directory structure.

We will have one Java class for an entry point. In the folder containing `pom.xml`,

```
mkdir -p src/main/java/com/stackoverflow/example
```

If you're on Windows, you need to (instead)

```
mkdir src\main\java\com\stackoverflow\example
```

Step three: Write the Java code (in the folder we just created)

Create a `Main.java` file containing (note I fixed an extra `)` bug in your LISP code)

```
package com.stackoverflow.example;

import javax.script.ScriptException;

import org.armedbear.lisp.scripting.AbclScriptEngine;
import org.armedbear.lisp.scripting.AbclScriptEngineFactory;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AbclScriptEngine scriptEngine = (AbclScriptEngine) new AbclScriptEngineFactory()
                    .getScriptEngine();
        try {
            scriptEngine.eval("(format t \"Hello, World!~%\")");
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Step four: Let's build and package our application.

In the folder containing the `pom.xml`,

```
mvn package
```

Step five: Run it

```
$ java -jar target/ColbertNightmare-jar-with-dependencies.jar
Hello, World!
```

Conclusion

Something like the above can be used to create an executable jar that uses ABCL. Also, [Stephen Colbert](https://youtu.be/aYfemLzDg6E) warned us about bears (before they were armed). I think they're an even bigger threat now.

Comment: Thanks you so much. Now I just need to work slime out.